# echarts scatter chart doesn't work title.textStyle.rich with text title

Tags: angular, typescript

I using angular 4 with ng2-echarts and I want to break word or change width of title text. I tried with title.textStyle.rich but it dosen't work

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=scatter-single-axis

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Same problem. Have you found some workaround? It seems that textStyle rich is not implemented at title ( https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/blob/master/src/component/title.js )